# NSUserDefaults Unique To Each Item

Tags: nsuserdefaults

In my app, I have numerous plants using this type of code which works great except when I want the user to save their own notes unique for each plant they view...

In my PerennialDataPurple.h

```
//  PerennialDataPurple.h
//  Created by John Lein Feb. 2017.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Lein Design Inc. All rights reserved.

@interface PerennialDataPurple : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* namethumb;

... 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* image3Title;

*@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* save_userNote;*

+(NSArray* )createMultipleSampleDishes;

@end
```

In my PerennialDataPurle.m I have the following code which works except again for saving notes...

```
//  PerennialDataPurple.m
//  Created by John Lein Feb. 2017.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Lein Design Inc. All rights reserved.

#import "PerennialDataPurple.h"

@implementation PerennialDataPurple

+(NSArray* )createSampleDishes{

PerennialDataPurple* purpleconeflower = [[PerennialDataPurple alloc] init];
purpleconeflower.name = @"Purple Cone Flower";
purpleconeflower.namethumb = @"Purple\rCone Flower";
... 
purpleconeflower.image3Description = @"Put some information in here to describe the design feature of image 3";
purpleconeflower.save_userNote = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userNotes"];
```

My detail controller (PicDetailController.h) (works except for save_userNote)

```
//
//  PicDetailController.h
//
//  Created by John Lein Feb. 2017.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Lein Design Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PerennialDataYellow.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import "SMPageControl.h"

@interface PicDetailController : UIViewController   <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

{

//    NSString *save_userNote;

    BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
    UIImage *blurrredImage;

    BOOL didEdit;
    IBOutlet UITextView *userNotes;

}

// allows me to use the plant label over again...

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *plantnameLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *plantnameLabel2;

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *userNotes;

- (IBAction)handleSingleTap:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)clearNote:(id)sender;

@end
```

My detail controller (PicDetailController.m) works and it does save the save_userNotes but it saves the same note for every plant I view.  So while it is successful in saving the note the user typed in, it is NOT unique for every record (plant)... I don't this something is being called back in the PerennialDataPurple.h file to make the connection...

```
//  PicDetailController.m
//  Created by John Lein Feb. 2017.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Lein Design Inc.. All rights reserved.

- (void)saveAction:(id)sender
{

NSString *valueToSave = userNotes.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"userNotes"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSString *text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userNotes"];
self.userNotes.text = text;

}
```

Notice in the first image - the note that was input by the user was saved... if I kill the app, force quit, and return it is saved... BUT NOT SAVED UNIQUE TO EACH PLANT... So when I view a second or third or forth image, the SAME USER NOTE APPEARS...

Any ideas how to make this work so EACH user note is unique to EACH plant...

I appreciate any help or insight...

[image][image]

Comment: If you want unique notes, use unique keys.

Comment: Thanks... I think that simple comment has made me think about unique notes = unique keys = the answer...

Comment: I may need to think about having the controller "know" which plant record it is currently viewing... thanks for your help. Much appreciated...